# Blazor Wasm HttpClientInterceptor Threading Issue

Tags: multithreading, blazor-webassembly

Using latest NET5 Hosted Blazor WASM.

I am using the HttpClientInterceptor to catch errors returned from the server.
All internal errors are catches and logged on the server and a error object are returned to the Blazor client.

I save the error object in local storage and then I navigate to the error page.
The problem is that calling e.GetCapturedContentAsync() somehow triggers the HttpClientInterceptor class multiple times.
Picture below is one call to the server that returns a 500 with an error object.
One of the entries holds data from the server the rest must be some kind of side effect of doing the async work.

[image]

When I am not calling e.GetCapturedContentAsync() then everthing works fine.

This is my HttpInterceptorService

```
public class HttpInterceptorService
{
    private readonly HttpClientInterceptor _interceptor;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navManager;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

    public HttpInterceptorService(HttpClientInterceptor interceptor, NavigationManager navManager,
        ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _interceptor = interceptor;
        _navManager = navManager;
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    public void MonitorEvent() => _interceptor.AfterSendAsync += InterceptResponse;

    private async Task InterceptResponse(object sender, HttpClientInterceptorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.Response == null || e.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return;


        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync("apiError");

        var responseCode = e.Response.StatusCode;
        ApiError apiError;


        var message = "Something went wrong, please contact Administrator";
        string detail;

        switch (responseCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                message = "The requested resource was not found.";
                detail = "The resource was not found. Please report the error if the problem persists.";
                apiError = new ApiError {Title = message, Status = (short) responseCode, Detail = detail};
                await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync("apiError", apiError);
                _navManager.NavigateTo("/ErrorPage");
                break;
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                message = "You are not authorized to access this resource. ";
                detail = "Please contact Helpdesk and the can help you get access to the resource.";
                apiError = new ApiError {Title = message, Status = (short) responseCode, Detail = detail};
                await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync("apiError", apiError);
                _navManager.NavigateTo("/ErrorPage");
                break;
            case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                apiError = await GetApiError500FromContent(e) ?? new ApiError();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiError.Id))
                {
                    apiError.Status = (short) responseCode;
                    apiError.Title = "Internal server error";
                }

                await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync($"apiError_{Guid.NewGuid()}", apiError);
                _navManager.NavigateTo("/ErrorPage");
                break;
            default:
                message = "Something went wrong, please contact Administrator";
                detail = "Please report the error if the problem persists.";
                apiError = new ApiError {Title = message, Status = (short) responseCode, Detail = detail};
                await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync($"apiError", apiError);
                _navManager.NavigateTo("/ErrorPage");
                break;
        }

        throw new HttpRequestException(message);
    }

    private static async Task<ApiError> GetApiError500FromContent(HttpClientInterceptorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var capturedContent = await e.GetCapturedContentAsync();
            var apiError = await capturedContent.ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiError>();
            if (apiError != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiError.Id))
            {
                return apiError;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void DisposeEvent() => _interceptor.AfterSendAsync -= InterceptResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer (: I forgot to call dispose after each api call